# Вытянуть id javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который при двойном клике фокусируется на ячейке таблицы и при нажатии enter вносятся изменения.

```
const send = (e) => {
  if ((e.type === 'blur' && e.target.contentEditable === 'true') || e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.contentEditable = false;

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'edit.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(`text=${encodeURIComponent(e.target.textContent)}`);
  }
};

[...document.querySelectorAll('td')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
    e.target.contentEditable = true;
    e.target.focus();
  });

  el.addEventListener('keypress', send);
  el.addEventListener('blur', send);
});
```

Как добавить в скрипт возможность при двойном клике вытянуть id конкретной строки чтобы обработчик edit.php знал в какой конкретно строке вносить изменения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну, если `ID`, у родителя (`TR`) наверное получить, `tr` и взять его `ID`. Как-то так `const id = e.target.closest('tr').id;` . Если `ID` самой ячейки, то сразу у `target` - `const id = e.target.id;`

```
const send = (e) => {
  if ((e.type === 'blur' && e.target.contentEditable === 'true') || e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.contentEditable = false;

    /** получаете, родителя в виде TR, и далее его ID. Ну или сразу у TD */
    const id = e.target.closest('tr').id;
    // const id = e.target.id;

    /** формируете, данные для сервера*/
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      text: encodeURIComponent(e.target.textContent),
      id
    });

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'edit.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data);
  }
};

[...document.querySelectorAll('td')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
    e.target.contentEditable = true;
    e.target.focus();
  });

  el.addEventListener('keypress', send);
  el.addEventListener('blur', send);
});
```

Comment: Юрий, а если id уже есть в базе данных и при клике нужно просто вытянуть данные этого id , <td><div id="6256916da8e54fbc1a692f69"></div></td> засунул в тд див и в нем нужный id как этот id вытянуть с помощью js?

Comment: const id = e.target.querySelector('div').id; - попробуйте так

Comment: <td id="6256916da8e54fbc1a692f69"></td> а если вот так сократить?

Comment: я не понимаю о чем вы пишите. Если ID находиться у TD - тогда я уже писал,  const id = e.target.id;

Comment: Спасибо все получилось только массив немножко не тот получился на выводе Array
(
    [{"text":"sada","id":"6256916da8e54fbc1a692f69"}] => 
)

Comment: как сделать массив вида Array
([text"] => sada ,[id] =>6256916da8e54fbc1a692f69) как было изначально в скрипте только добавить id

Comment: xhr.send(`text=${encodeURIComponent(e.target.textContent)}&id=${id}`); - думаю как-то так

Comment: Работает благодарю!